# React native private deployment

Tags: ios, react-native, ota

I've to create a mobile app for my small company (150 users).

They use both Android and IOS device, and the only native feature I need is Notifications Push..

Cause of the notifications, I can't go pwa (ios doesn't support), so I would try react native app.

This app is for private usage, so I can't deploy it via App Store, but I can use the "enterprise program".

The problem is the price.. It Will cost 300$ every year, for only one app ?

I think I can leave the program once upon a time the app is deployed.. But have to subsribe when I'll have to update..

I've see the OTA possibility. Do you think I can deploy and Update via OTA (Codepush)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Expo](http://expo.io), it might be just you need. Comes with push notifications support out of the box, the pre-release/beta development/distribution experience is just beautiful. One-click update (without any OTA settings, configuration, hassle) of your app's JS bundle, QR code sharing, and lots more.

Also, you can use TestFlight (together with Expo) if you guys don't want to pay for anything, but that app will expire after 90 days (and you'll have to re-submit a build every 90 days).

Comment: OK so the best thing is to pay I earn